# why does this happen with lists in python

Tags: python, string, list, variable-assignment, mutable

When I assign one list to another, I see that upon changing one of the elements in one list, the other element is automatically assigned with that value.

What is the reason for this behavior?

```
>>> a = [1,2,3] # create a list
>>> b = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
40307408
>>> id(b)
40307408
>>> a[2] = 5
>>> b
[1, 2, 5]
>>> b[1] = 10
>>> a
[1, 10, 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because objects `a` and `b` reference the same object (as you have observed by checking both objects' `id`s). If you change a value in one, the other will change as well. It's like `b` is a clone of `a`, but will continue being a clone.

To avoid this behaviour, you can do:

```
b = a[:]
```

Which assigns `b` a copy of `a`.

Or:

```
b = list(a)
```

Or:

```
import copy
b = copy.copy(a) # The copy module can be useful for nested lists.
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `b = a`, you're actually just assigning another name to the same object, as `id(a)` and `id(b)` show. If you want to copy a to b you should use either `b = a[:]` or `b = list(a)`. In that case, a and b will have separate lifecycles. Try calling id() and check.